# Google Maps API using/getting the value of outputs map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to make a webpage that verifies an address, so I used Google maps api, below is the stucture of the webpage, once the user inputs an address then clicks the submit button the API shows a map of the place. Here a sample input:

User's Input:
199 Freestone Road, Sladevale QLD 4370, Australia

then Button click

Google creates/shows a map of the place.

What I'm trying to do is get the "Australia" part of the user's input to call my image once the submit button is click, however it doesn't work in a country name that is seperated by a space ex. "Hong Kong" etc., so I was wondering if I could use the generated map by google to call my image. Is this possible?How can I accomplish this? Suggestions/Comments/Opinions are highly appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few ideas...

1. Put a dummy/sample address in the top text area with the street on one line, the city on the next line and the country on the last line to suggest to the user that the country should be on a line on its own, rather than comma-separated.
2. Build in a list of countries, from somewhere like [here](http://www.state.gov/s/inr/rls/4250.htm) and look for them explicitly.
3. Offer the countries in a drop-down list.
4. Send the last word as a country to the google API, and if it fails, try taking the last two words.